# How can I prove that for $2$ finite dimensional matrices $A,B: [A,B] = i$ is impossible?

Tags: linear-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I was told that for any finite dimensional Hilbert space, $[A,B]=i$ is impossible, while it is possible for an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. How can I show it is impossible for finite dimensional?

**Edit:** I just realized it's trivial with by taking trace. But is it possible to show without taking trace?

Comment: The trace of a commutator of matrices is zero.

Comment: kill me........

Comment: @Chubmaster25 I believe this is out of scope for this site. You'll need killer.stackexchange or similar.

Comment: The trace argument gets directly to the main reason. Any other argument will need to be carefully considered, since we really do need to work in a finite dimensional space over a field of characteristic $0$ (else there are examples where the claim fails).

Answer (score 5):

The trace is the best way, but just for fun:

Suppose $AB - BA = I$ and $v$ is an eigenvector of $BA$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then,
$$ABv - BAv = v \implies ABv = (\lambda + 1)v \implies BABv = (\lambda + 1)Bv.$$
If $\lambda \neq -1$, then we have $Bv \neq 0$, hence $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $BA$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda + 1$. On the other hand, if $\lambda = -1$, then we must have $ABv = 0$. Since $v \neq 0$, this means that $A$ or $B$ is not invertible, and hence neither is $BA$, which means $\lambda + 1 = 0$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$.

In either case, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$, then so is $\lambda + 1$. Hence, there are an infinite number of eigenvalues of $BA$!

Comment: This is actually a really neat way to also see precisely why both the assumption of characteristic $0$ and of finite dimensionality is needed.

Comment: Wow thanks thats really cool. What is the characteristic 0 for?

Comment: @Chubmaster25 The condition that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue implies $\lambda + 1$ is an eigenvalue only produces an infinite number of eigenvalues when the field is characteristic $0$, otherwise the sequence $\lambda, \lambda + 1, \lambda + 2, \ldots$ is periodic.